# Message: This row was successfully committed to the database. However, a problem occurred 

Tags: sql-server

I have a table in SQL Server 2005 whose primary key is an identity column (increment 1), and I also have a default value set for one of the other columns.

When I open the table in SQL Server Management Studio and type in a new record into the table, the inserted values are not displayed, and I get the following message on save:

[image: messageonsave]

However, if the table has **either** an identity column, **or** one or more columns with a default value specified, the inserted value(s) will be displayed in the table after a save.  And can be edited.

I frequently create test data in ssms this way and this issue makes it cumbersome to do some things I would like to.

Is there any way around this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Right click on it and say Execute SQL...it should not display it(error)..its just sql server way of doing things..since it inserts the identity column later..You should not add records in that way in the first place.

Comment: Thanks. I should have asked a long time ago!

Answer (score 1):

You should not add records to a database that way! It can have unfortunate side effects (especially on large tables) as you have discovered.

Records for lookup tables should be added through rerunable scripts. Those scripts should in source control. This makes them easy to promote from dev to Qa to staging to prod.

Test records should also be done in scripts (including scripts to remove the test records) so that you can run thenm on other environments as well as being able to delete and recreate them if some process you are testing went bad. These too should eb in source control (as should all database changes which also should not be done through the GUI).

Comment: I'm not talking about production environments, or data for unit tests. I'm just creating a table on my development machine and running against a copy of a production table to test a small bit of new code.

Comment: It's still better and more reliable to create a script.